# Flutter Disable Button on ListView Builder

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

Hi I am trying to i have a listview.builder which renders custom card design that i create the problem is that i want to disable button on the card on which user tap but it end up disabling all the cards button
here is the code

```
Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return CardDesign(
                  index: i,
                  infolist: list,
                  buttonOnTap: () async {
                    await updateJoin(list[i].joined += 1, list[i].id);
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(
                          tournamentinfo: list[i],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }),
```

the buttonOnTap Method is the one that i want to disable but only for that Specific button in the list and only for that user

Comment: do you save that id on a list during tapping? If so, then you can check first if that id exists already then you can disable the button by assigning it a null function.